# Javascript:write a string with multiple lines to a csv file for downloading

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to write a string that has multiple lines (comes from the server side) into a csv file for user to download in browser. However, using my code, I only get the csv files with all the data in a single line. 
Here is my code:

```
function getReport(){
    var report = "a,b,c,d;1,2,3,4;";
    //console.log(report);
    var csvcontent="";
    while (report.indexOf(";")!=-1)
    {
        csvcontent=csvcontent+ report.substring(0,report.indexOf(";"))+"\n";
        report=report.substring(report.indexOf(";")+1);
    }

    console.log(csvcontent);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href     = 'data:attachment/csv,' + csvcontent;
    a.target   = '_blank';
    a.download = 'myFile.csv';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    //console.log("ok");
    a.click();
}
```

In the downloaded csv file, all the data will in a single line a,b,c,d1,2,3,4.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead
`a.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;base64,' + window.btoa(csvcontent);`
It converts the data to base64 which properly encodes the new line character. Why it doesn't work in your method I'm really not sure. One caveat is the `btoa` function won't work in older browsers check out this question for more information [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Comment: hmm, this method actually works. So the without this conversion to base 64, the program just cannot recognize the new line character?

Comment: @Koshien I'm not sure, but somewhere in creating the data URI the new line character gets removed unless you do something like base64 encode it.